# Basic Vite Vanilla Setup

Tags: javascript, html, vite

I want to set up a very basic project with [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) vanilla

I scaffolded the project with `yarn create @vitejs/app`

Now I adjusted the following files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Chat</h1>
        Message
      <br/>
      <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

**main.js**

```
console.log('hello main.js')

const chatInput = document.querySelector('textarea')

export function sendMessage() {
    let message =  chatInput.value
    window.alert(message)
    chatInput.value = "";
}
```

I am now getting the following error in the browser console when I click the "Send" button

```sh
client.ts:13 [vite] connecting...
main.js:35 hello main.js
client.ts:43 [vite] connected.
(index):18 Uncaught ReferenceError: sendMessage is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):18)
```

**Workaround**

I can work around the problem by adding an event listener to the button instead of adding the onclick directly in the HTML

```js
const sendButton = document.querySelector('button')
sendButton.addEventListener('click', sendMessage)
```

But why can't you use the first approach with `onclick="sendMessage()"` within the HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Main.js` is added as a `type=module`. Module creates a scope to avoid name collisions.

You can either expose your function to the `window` object

```
import { sendMessage } from './events.js'
window.sendMessage = sendMEssage
```

Or use the `addEventListener` method to bind the handler like you're doing.